# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: WAS 8.5.5.13 throws this error when deploying an application

Tags: websphere-8, was

WE are deploying a newly built version of an application in WAS 8.5.5.13 with JDK 1.8 and while startup the app fails with below error.
Two things:-
1.) We are having a JVM classpath set -   /apps/BD.war/BD.ear/WEB-INF/lib 
2.) classloader we tried - PARENT_LAST as well as PARENT_FIRST

## LOGS:

```
    [1/11/19 11:30:48:264 EST] 0000007f DeployedAppli W WSVR0206E: Module, BD.war, of application, BD.ear/deployments/BD, failed to start<br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:277 EST] 00000080 ApplicationMg A WSVR0221I: Application started: ibmasyncrsp<br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:277 EST] 00000080 CompositionUn A WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=ibmasyncrsp in BLA WebSphere:blaname=ibmasyncrsp started.<br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:280 EST] 0000007f ApplicationMg W WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, BD <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:280 EST] 0000007f ApplicationMg A WSVR0217I: Stopping application: BD <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:363 EST] 0000007f ApplicationMg A WSVR0220I: Application stopped: BD <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:467 EST] 0000007f FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /logs/was/FDS/ffdc/MSUDR_A1_APP_c3772b2f_19.01.11_11.30.48.4404163186997035868245.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl 2288 <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:467 EST] 0000007f CompositionUn E WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=BD in BLA WebSphere:blaname=BD failed to start. <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:469 EST] 0000007f FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /logs/was/FDS/ffdc/MSUDR_A1_APP_c3772b2f_19.01.11_11.30.48.4682386415146767366256.txt com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl 297 <br/>
[1/11/19 11:30:48:470 EST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@b53ae56a <br/>
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException:  <br/>
Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: loading constraint violation when overriding method &quot;javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V&quot; <br/>
during creation of class &quot;org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer&quot;: <br/>
loader &quot;com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@2e351854&quot; of class &quot;org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer&quot; and loader &quot;org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@7f9aac98&quot; of class &quot;javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer&quot; have different types for the method signature <br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:432) <br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)<br/>
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)<br/>
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)<br/>
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)<br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)<br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)<br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)<br/>
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)<br/>
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)<br/>
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)<br/>
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)<br/>
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)<br/>
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)<br/>
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)<br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:407)<br/>
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:170)<br/>
```

Comment: Is the error identical with both PARENT_FIRST and PARENT_LAST? This specific error is of a type that usually only occurs in PARENT_LAST environments, and is likely caused by a copy of the Servlet API packaged in your application, which you should remove (you can't override the server's Servlet API with your own version).

Comment: Yes it initially happened with PARENT_FIRST and then we tried PARENT_LAST - the same exact error. So I will find and remove the servlet API implementation and see.. Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I checked my jars and there is no specific jar to override the Servlet API which I must remove.

Comment: Are there any other jars that might contain Java EE or SE APIs (basically any class in a "javax" package)? The loading constraint violation is only possible in a duplicate visibility scenario, where a class is loaded by two separate loaders.